# ASP.NET C# pass temporary file to html object tag directly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, file, temporary

I need pass pdf (or other) file to `<object>` tag from server (e.g. as filestream) for documents preview in modal.

```
   <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="previewElement" class="view-doc-border">
                <object data="" type="application/pdf">

                </object>
            </div>
   </div>
```

I using external service for getting pdf file, which returning file without saving. Also I **can't save this file** in file system (on server), I need use it **only as temporary file** and such pass it to html view. 
**How can I implement this?**
Thanks!